# Group rows by the same value in the field, while matching on partial value only

Tags: mysql, sql, string, group-by, count

I have a table that has many rows (between a few 1000s to a few million).
I need my query to do the following:

- group results by the same part of the value in the field;
- order by the biggest group first.

The table has mostly values that have only some part are similar (and i.e. suffix would be different). Since the number of similar values is huge - I cannot predict all of them.

Here is i.e. my table:

```
+--------+-----------+------+
|   Id   | Uri       | Run  |
+--------+-----------+------+
|  15145 | select_123|    Y |
|  15146 | select_345|    Y |
|  15148 | delete_123|    N |
|  15150 | select_234|    Y |
|  15314 | delete_334|    N |
|  15315 | copy_all  |    N |
|  15316 | merge_all |    Y |
|  15317 | select_565|    Y |
|  15318 | copy_all  |    Y |
|  15319 | delete_345|    Y |
+--------+-----------+------+
```

What I would like to see, something like this (the Count part is desirable but not required):

```
+-----------+------+
| Uri       | Count|
+-----------+------+
|  select   |  4   |
|  delete   |  3   |
|  copy_all |  2   |
|  merge_all|  1   |
+-----------+------+
```

Comment: Look into using LIKE 'select%', LIKE 'delete%', etc. patterns. This allows you to include all strings that start with 'select' or 'delete', etc. no matter what follows the constant in question. Check out this article for more in-depth examples: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/

Comment: Substring_index would also work here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MySQL 5.x, you can strip the trailing `_` and digits from the `Uri` value using this expression:

```
LEFT(Uri, LENGTH(Uri) - LOCATE('_', REVERSE(Uri)))
```

Using a `REGEXP` test to see if the `Uri` ends in `_` and some digits, we can then process the `Uri` according to that and then `GROUP BY` that value to get the counts:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Uri REGEXP '_[0-9]+$' THEN LEFT(Uri, LENGTH(Uri) - LOCATE('_', REVERSE(Uri)))
       ELSE Uri
       END AS Uri2,
       COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM data
GROUP BY Uri2
```

Output:

```
Uri2        Count
copy_all    2
delete      3
merge_all   1
select      4
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0052e/6)

Comment: Hey @Nick... I am late to the party, but, regardless: Congrats on the 100k!

Comment: @GMB thanks - it took a while but I got there eventually. Not answering so much these days...

Comment: Not that long, really. Yes did not see you a lot around lately. Cheers anyway!

Comment: Thanks @Nick Very hard to pick the "Answer" post. :)

Answer (score 1):

The format of the string makes it uneasy to parse it with string functions.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can truncate the string with `regexp_replace()`, then `group by` and `order by`:

```
select regexp_replace(uri, '_\\d+$', '') new_uri, count(*) cnt
from mytable
group by new_uri
order by cnt desc
```

Comment: This will return `copy` instead of `copy_all`.

Comment: `substr_index` should be `substring_index`.

Comment: @Barmar: fixed. Now our answers are very similar though.

Comment: Thanks @GMB Very hard to pick the "Answer" post. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL 8.x, you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` to remove the numeric suffixes from `select_XXX` and `delete_XXX`, then group by the result.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(uri, '_[0-9]+$', '') AS new_uri, COUNT(*) as count
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY new_uri
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar ! Very hard to pick the "Answer" post. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below and create a view and using the case expression + substr find which are 'select' and 'delete'.

Following the view you can query it with the count/group_by.

```
WITH view_1 AS (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN substr(uri, 1, 6) = 'select'       THEN
                substr(uri, 1, 6)
            WHEN substr(uri, 1, 6) = 'delete'       THEN
                substr(uri, 1, 6)
            ELSE uri
        END AS uri
    FROM
        your_table
)
SELECT
    uri,
    COUNT(uri) as "Count"
FROM
    view_1
GROUP BY
    uri
ORDER BY count(uri) DESC;
```

Output will be

```
delete      5
merge_all   4
select      3
copy_all    3
```